# Upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 has broken code generation - getting DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-generation

I'm trying to migrate my solution (an ASP.NET web app with about a dozen dependent assemblies) to VS 2010 and am hitting some new build errors.

```
Error   909 Running transformation: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:
Could not find a part of the path 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
10.0\Common7\IDE\SomeProject\Templates\MyTemplate.xml'.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
```

The problem is pretty clear - it's trying to load the XML for my generated code, but instead of looking in $(SolutionDir)\SomeProject\Templates\MyTemplate.xml, it's looking in .\SomeProject\Templates\MyTemplate.xml (where . is the Visual Studio executable working directory, I presume).

There seems to be entirely too much magic behind the scenes and I can't locate any kind of preferences or config settings that define this. Seems like most of the generator config is in the registry.

Has anybody encountered something similar before?

Update: I'm running Visual Studio 2010 Professional 10.0.30319 RTMRel. As part of the migration I also allowed it to update my projects from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.

Comment: what version of vs2010 are you using? any chance u are using a beta build? There was a similar issue in the beta's which seemed to have been fixed in the RC http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/472649/vs2010-external-tools-working-directory-variables-not-working

Comment: It's the release version - I've edited the question to reflect this. This looks like you're on the right track, though. The T4 generation tool isn't setup an as External Tool in VS (though it is an external tool). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but in the interest of helping others that may come along later, there are two things that can fix this.

First of all, the first line in your template needs to set hostspecific to true.

It should look something like this:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
```

Second, there's a better, and more reliable way to resolve the path on the host.

You probably have a line of code that looks something like this:

```
const string inputFile = @"<relative path to EDMX file>"
```

A better way to code this is as follows:

```
string rootPath = Host.ResolvePath(String.Empty);
string relativePath = @"<relative path toe EDMX file>";
string inputFile = Path.Combine(rootPath, relativePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into [CodeSmith Generator](http://www.codesmithtools.com/), it has many advantages over T4 and you won't have to wait a very long time for a bug fix.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski